# Set the divider for the popup menu

Tags: android, popup, overflow, divider

How can I set the divider for the action bar overflow popup menu?

This is my popup menu style:

```
<style name="PopupMenu.Silver" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_silver</item>
</style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Material theme removes dividers. This is the simple solution to this problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little my friend.  I am in a same boat and tried lot of solutions but none would work for me.  What do you mean by removing Material theme and how do I have to do it?  appreciate your help...